# 403 Forbidden почему?

Tags: php, парсер

Есть [ссылка](https://mdskip.taobao.com/core/initItemDetail.htm?isAreaSell=false&showShopProm=false&isRegionLevel=false&tryBeforeBuy=false&cartEnable=true&cachedTimestamp=1472028055158&isSecKill=false&service3C=true&queryMemberRight=true&tmallBuySupport=true&isApparel=false&addressLevel=2&itemId=528019292012&offlineShop=false&household=false&isPurchaseMallPage=false&sellerPreview=false&isForbidBuyItem=false&isUseInventoryCenter=false&callback=setMdskip&timestamp=1472028415784&isg=AtzcfYpEnfC74UqUlcVPCgQOLPCGhYB/&isg2=AvHxrNgHAj0h_a40KIkwU-YtAH3zo2VQgXX6bNMOPbjX-gRMHS0KIN9aOjlm) в ней лежит нужные информации:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему когда пытаюсь зайти выскакивает ошибка 403 Forbidden как парсит такие страницы?

Comment: Потому что сервер вам запрещает ее посещать. Наверное потому что вы пытаетесь ее парсить...

Comment: ведь браузер видит и читает эти информации. как тогда парсить как браузер?

Comment: Берете Wireshark, смотрите как браузер ее получает. Сравниваете с тем как вы. Думаете.

Comment: Не надо парсить как браузер. Если вы видите красивую вещь на выставке, это не значит, что вы можете забрать ее себе домой. Не надо брать чужое. Это плохо.

Comment: В интернете это естественно, для того и придумали парсинги.

Answer (score 2):

Если это хром или FF, то кликаем правой кнопкой на запрос в дебаггере и нажимаем "Copy as cURL".

Запрос будет скопирован точно таким же каким его посылает браузер.
Перевести на php дело техники.

По факту, думаю, там будет достаточно передачи в запросе одной или нескольких кук, может быть еще реферера. Нужно проверять.